# When is res.on(end) called in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have the following fairly simply code (in coffeescript):

```
http = require 'http'

options =
  hostname: 'somewebsite.com'
  port: 80,
  path: '/'

server = http.createServer  (request, response) ->
  response.writeHead 200, 'text/html'
  req = http.get options, (res) ->
    res.on 'data', (data) -> 
      console.log 'GETTING IT'
      response.write data
    res.on 'end', () ->
      console.log 'GOT IT'
      response.end()

server.listen 80
```

I was under the impression that once the request was complete, res.on 'end' was called, yet whenever I execute the code, the callback is called multiple times. Any help?

Comment: The res.end event will get called when the http.get (res) is done receiving data.  Are you sure it's not just that you're proxying multiple requests?

Comment: Did you even intend to write a proxy server?  You're not basing your responses off of the request object...  All this server does is respond with data from somewebsite.com/ every time...

Comment: I did not intend to write a proxy server, I'm simply trying to find my way around node.js. I think the issue I'm coming across at this point is simply the web browser sending multiple requests to the server (one for the favicon, for example).

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue I was coming across here is not that `res.on('end')` was being called multiple times, but that I was making multiple requests, because every request to the server is being handled through this loop. so, when it tried to load the favicon it would go through the whole process again, and when it tries to load any css files or anything else included in the html of the file I was 'proxying' it would go through the process again for that portion.

Comment: This is basicly how node.js is designed. There are various frameworks that simplify writing a webserver and routing requests. I personaly like http://expressjs.com/, and would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Here check this example out, I think it will help clarify what is going on in your code.  Hit these two urls localhost:8888 and localhost:9999

```
http = require 'http'
somePortNum = 9999
options =
    hostname: 'localhost'
    port: somePortNum,
    path: '/'

proxyServer = http.createServer  (request, response) ->
  response.writeHead 200, 'text/html'
  response.write 'This server is a proxy server, we will make a request to the server on localhost:9999 and post the response below:\n'
  req = http.get options, (res) ->
    res.on 'data', (data) ->
      response.write data
    res.on 'end', () ->
      response.end()

proxyServer.listen 8888

server2 = http.createServer  (request, response) ->

  response.writeHead 200, 'text/html'
  response.write 'This is a very simple server, it just says hello world'
  response.end()

server2.listen somePortNum
```